# extraneous stars when using org-indent-mode

Tags: org-mode, indentation

Since a recent update from the org-mode repository, if I turn on `org-indent-mode`, all lines show up indented with stars rather than spaces.  Here's an example of how it looks:

[image]

Here's the file without indenting:

[image]

I am using Emacs 24.4.1 on Linux.

Do you know what may be causing this?

Comment: both look identical to my eyes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by setting the `org-indent` font to have the same foreground and background color.  To do this, in my `custom-set-faces`, I included the following line:

```
'(org-indent ((t (:background "#181818" :foreground "#181818"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A theme tweak may fix the problem: you can adapt the following .emacs excerpt code for your case:

```
(let ((class '((class color))))    
     (custom-theme-set-faces
     'leuven
     `(org-hide ((,class (:foreground "#000000"))))))
```

My theme is `leuven`. I tried to change the color `#000000` which changed the color oh the "hidden" stars.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that helped me was to delete the older theme packages that I was using.